# preventing users to copy displayed image in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net, image, asp.net-mvc-4, copy

I'm developing a website in Asp.net MVC 4. 
Part of the site must display images that their showing right is only belong to this site and users can only view this images through site without ability to copy them using either "save as .." option or copying image URLs using web developing tools.

How can I implement this scenario using MVC4.
These images can be stored either in web host or database. Witch one is preferred for this work?

Comment: If you send images to client machines you will not be able to prevent the users from saving them.   You could add a watermark or banner (copyright...) to the images before sending them.

Comment: Atleast you can do this, instead of using `<img>` use `<div>` and set background image of that div, so that image will shown, but on right clicking on image, no download or save as image will be shown, but yes, if some can sniffs through inspector in developer console, then they can download image.